# Check string in PHP

Tags: php, string, validation

I want to check some string before sending an email. 
I have 3 fields: `name` +  `email` + `text`

I'm wondering if `mysql_escape_string` is good even  If I'll not insert the values into a sql table. So I used:

**PHP code:**

```
  $name = trim($name);
  $name = strip_tags($name);
   # etc
```

**Question:**
 
It's enough?

**EDIT:**
I want to remove HTML Tags (Expet `<p>` & `<br />` from the Text Field) + Trim the strings

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Strip HTML tags? Encode HTML tags?

Comment: "to check some string" is not quite a good description of what you want to achieve. What do you want to filter out? Do you want to validate it? encode it? get rid of the tags?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336776/xss-filtering-function-in-php

Comment: simple solution is validate the input fields to the visitors

Comment: @Zulkhaery Basrul  It's not a duplicate. Read my question, I ask if It's enough

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` is never a good option, not even when you want to insert the string in a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all HTML Tags except `<p> & <br />`:

```
$name = strip_tags(trim($name), '<p><br>');
```

Second argument to [`strip_tags`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strip_tags) is the allowed tags. But you can not specify which attributes to preserve or drop for the tags with that function.

I'm pretty sure how to do that has been already asked on this site, so you should [take a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+strip+tags+and+attributes) or look at this duplicate:

- [PHP function to strip tags, except a list of whitelisted tags and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387445/367456)

Comment: But it doesn't strip any attributes like `onclick`! Example: `<p onclick="alert('Hello!');">Some text</p>`

Comment: @ComFreek: As a good practice, you should not have inline event handlers in the first place. Your javascript code should be separate and unobstrusive.

Comment: @Sarfraz That's not the point if it's about *sanitizing user input*.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can pass strip_tags what you want to allow

example:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><br><br>';
// Allow <p> and <br>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><br>');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want to read the documentation  of `filter_var`, `filter_var_array`, `filter_input` and `filter_input_array`. That's the modern way to go, with this you're able to compose complex filtering and sanatizing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't create this snippet, and I've misplaced the source, but this function seems to do a decent job of sanitizing for me and my low-traffic sites:

```
#   Sanitizer function - removes forbidden tags, including script tags
function strip_tags_attributes( $str, 
    $allowedTags = array('<a>','<b>','<blockquote>','<br>','<cite>','<code>','<del>','<div>','<em>','<ul>','<ol>','<li>','<dl>','<dt>','<dd>','<img>','<ins>','<u>','<q>','<h3>','<h4>','<h5>','<h6>','<samp>','<strong>','<sub>','<sup>','<p>','<table>','<tr>','<td>','<th>','<pre>','<span>'), 
    $disabledEvents = array('onclick','ondblclick','onkeydown','onkeypress','onkeyup','onload','onmousedown','onmousemove','onmouseout','onmouseover','onmouseup','onunload') )
{       
    if( empty($disabledEvents) ) {
        return strip_tags($str, implode('', $allowedTags));
    }
    return preg_replace('/<(.*?)>/ies', "'<' . preg_replace(array('/javascript:[^\"\']*/i', '/(" . implode('|', $disabledEvents) . ")=[\"\'][^\"\']*[\"\']/i', '/\s+/'), array('', '', ' '), stripslashes('\\1')) . '>'", strip_tags($str, implode('', $allowedTags)));
}
```

HTH.