# Use str_replace to remove certain html tags

Tags: php, str-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP function to strip tags, except a list of whitelisted tags and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387445/php-function-to-strip-tags-except-a-list-of-whitelisted-tags-and-attributes)

I have a database with some unwanted html tags, I need to keep some of html formatting. I tried to use str_replace to remove the unwanted tags but it doesn't work:

```
$newdrp = str_replace('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"><html>',"",$row_Recordset1['full_description']);
```

Comment: You should add more information about what your source text looks like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want to allow certain tags you could use:

```
$newdrp = strip_tags($row_Recordset1['full_description'], '<span> <div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the html then use this :

```
$newdrp = strip_tags($text);
```

If you just want to remove some of the html then use this :

```
$newdrp = strip_tags($text, '<div> <a>');
```